# How can we get the data passed to WorkManager WorkRequest?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is there a way to get the data passed to WorkManager WorkRequest?

I need to list all scheduled works including its respective input data, but then I have to save the input data separately in shared prefs of a DB, then delete it when work is done. It's not very practical.

Looks like WorkManager has its own DataBase to save all the info. How can we access it?

Sample with input data:

```
    // Create the Constraints
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

// Define the input
val imageData = workDataOf(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_URI to imageUriString)

// Bring it all together by creating the WorkRequest; this also sets the back off criteria
val uploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>()
        .setInputData(**inputData**)
        .setConstraints(constraints)        
        .setBackoffCriteria(
                BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 
                OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS, 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()
```

Comment: Why do you need to delete the data? When the work is finished all work-related info is gone. Do you want to just access the data later after the works are scheduled?

Comment: @YavorMitev The idea is to list all scheduled works with the respective data passed to them before they are completed, not to delete them.

Comment: I had the same question and have not found a way to lookup a WorkRequest (or its Worker) after it is enqueued or running.  A possible workaround is to store the data you want to query in a Tag instead of in InputData.  You can query the WorkInfos of enqueued or running WorkRequests, and a WorkInfo includes the set of tags.